# Trying to be able to make updates to the prices and inventory in a simple, three product inventory program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I very new to Python, so anything would be very helpful. I need to be able to make adjustments to the price and stock of three inventory items if the user inputs  code 3. The user should be able to select the product they want to

Comment: Do you really think this kind of code works if you want to sell 40 different colored pens, of 10 different brands? I doubt it. I do not get what your question is, its too much code, and not enough [minimal verifyable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). what is your question, where is the error message and stacktrace?

Comment: There is no error .. I'm just wondering where to begin when making user input updates to the quantity of each item and price of each item which are listed in products[1] and products[2]

Comment: maybe you should start rewriting some of your `if's`  to begin with:  `if inquiry == 'pen' or  inquiry == 'Pen' or inquiry == 'PEN':` == `if inquiry.lower() == 'pen' :` that would reduce your code by about 2/3rds.